# Div element isn't reaching the left of the browser page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a menu at the top of the page as seen in a tutorial, but the menu icon isn't reaching the left of the page.

I've tried editing the margin and padding tags, but nothing works. [Here is the link to the tutorial](https://youtu.be/yytscwxx1pk?list=PL0eyrZgxdwhxNGMWROnaY35NLyEjTqcgB&t=1234)

```css
.nav-main {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.btn-toggle-nav {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #F98F39;
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/500");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 60%;
  background-position: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  padding: 0 5px;
  background-color: #1B1B1B
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-main">
  <div class="btn-toggle-nav"></div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Project</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Biography</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<aside class="nav-sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li><span href="#">More</span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Original Write-Up</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Procedure</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Why We Started</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">What We Hope To Accomplish</a></li>
  </ul>
</aside>
```

So everything shows up perfectly, except that the main div is slightly more to the right, leaving a white space on the left. But the sidebar is fully aligned with the left, making the page look off with the menu icon and the sidebar not being aligned with each other.

Comment: Set `left: 0` on `.nav-main`.

Comment: Hi. Not sure what your entire setup is but you may try and reset the box sizing for all your properties. `* {box-sizing: border-box}` then remove all padding and margin for the `body` and any outer `div` thats wraps your nav-main

Answer (score 0):

By historical reasons all browsers has a offset for many things also the body tag. 
the most easy way is to reset everything first to a zero border. That you do not have byselv, it is a common problem. So someone fix it already. Maybe try this link [Normalize Github](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

There are some of this kind of reset everything to zero scripts out. So try it and see if the gap is gone. If so you know it was a browser default issue :)

Comment: This didn't work, but thank you. I managed to fix the problem on my own.

Comment: So why not post your solution to help other peoples ?